# Lag on fixed element on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, retina-display, lag

I have an issue on my fixed element.

If I scroll to the offset "slowy", I have no problem. It's good.
But if I scroll to the offset "very quickly", my `fix` class is removed after `XX`ms.

```
var menu = $(".category");
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > parseInt(menu.offset().top, 10)) {
        menu.find(".menu-wrapper").addClass("fix");
    }
    else {
        menu.find(".menu-wrapper").removeClass("fix");
    }
});
```

I already use this to the fixed element:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Example: (In this video, I deliberately slowed down a portion of the video for you to see the lag)

https://vid.me/GMnW

**Someone can help me please?**

```
Chrome 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit)
OS X 10.9 
MacBook Pro 13" 2014 — Retina Display
```

Comment: Chrome doesn't execute functions assocated with `scroll` event each repaint while scrolling using MacBook's touchpad or touchscreen, because it would cause performance issues and stutter. Unless you find a way to do this with pure CSS, I'm afraid there's no way to avoid this.

Comment: @m132 where did you got that information from? I got the same problem, animations works smoothly in safari but firefox and chrome are choppy. But I can't find anywhere information on how to fix it.